# Which one is correct in this context, "was new for me" vs. "is new for me"?

Tags: grammar

I sent an email update to my friend. He replied:

> I saw his reply myself when I was in there, but response submitted by him ***is new for me***

Now he has seen the response, and I think it has gone in past. Should he not have used *was new for me* rather than *is new for me* in his reply to me?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you are trying to say..

Comment: I think it would be better if you correct your entire question before correcting your friend's reply.

Answer (score 1):

Either could be correct depending on the context of the sentence.  "Is new to me" indicates it is new at present.  As in: I saw his reply when I was there (in the past), but the response submitted by him is new to me (now).  As in, looking at his response then, it now is new.
The past version "was new" implies it all happened in the past. As in: I saw his reply when I was there and it then seemed new to me.
Really, this is a badly written sentence, as it is unclear what is meant by the response and the reply. A clearer sentence would probably clear up the whole problem.